# Extension to add button "Report to Bugzilla"?

Tags: mediawiki, integration

We have:

- internal MediaWiki installation for internal documents (we don't use it in
  completely wiki-like style—only maintainers should normally make changes)
- internal Bugzilla installation for internal issues including these internal
  documents on the MediaWiki site

Now only the icing on the cake is missing: an automatic button that would appear on each page, being able to

- open a Bugzilla page
- pre-fill some fields with information about that page Basically, name

What I imagine as a best solution would be a sibling to the ubiquitous "[edit]" button, probably sitting next to it, like in this mock-up:

[image: Mock-up of a Bugzilla "report" button]

Answer (score 1):

You might be coming at this backwards.
Rather than looking for a MediaWiki extension, you probably just need to do a minor edit to your template. Bugzilla has a feature that lets you fill out the submission form and then re-use those values later. But the presentation's a little weird. The button is labeled "Remember values as bookmarkable template." Once you click that, though, you're just redirected to a page that offers you a link to use, with a bunch of parameters. It'll look something like this:

```
https://bugzilla.example.com/enter_bug.cgi?alias=&bug_severity=normal&cf_version=2.9&comment=COMMENT_GOES_HERE&component=docs&contenttypeentry=&contenttypemethod=autodetect&contenttypeselection=text%2Fplain&data=&description=&form_name=enter_bug&keywords=kw1%2Ckw2&maketemplate=Remember%20values%20as%20bookmarkable%20template&op_sys=Windows&product=whatever&short_desc=SUMMARY%20GOES%20HERE&version=git%20master
```

(Some of those parameters are for custom fields and won't mean anything to you.)
Once you have that URL, just add it to your template wherever you want it to occur. Page-specific information should be easy enough to include via MediaWiki's own templating.

Note this feature seems to be optional. For example, Mozilla's own installation doesn't use it, but Gnome does. You might need to speak to your admin if it isn't you.

Comment: Yes, I know this feature I'm already using this in some pure HTML documents, but I need also MW to generate the link for every page or even section.

Comment: (OP wasn't much clear about that--edited.)

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this doesn't apply. (Unless you're *specifically* looking for something that magically inserts the link for you? But even then this is potentially so simple no one's bothered.) Adding it to your template would place it on every page. Some trivial PHP would generate your page-specific information, eg. `&description=This bug is about <?php $this->data['displaytitle']?>` (Obviously you should URL-encode that; left plain for clarity.)

Comment: "But even then this is potentially so simple no one's bothered" -- Well, then I'm Mr. No One, because *that's what my question was about* :) I mean, I did know th BZ part but I'm a complete n00b with MW

Answer (score 0):

You could create a modal popup which contains a form with fields that match the ones from bugzilla and post to the bugzilla page. Using dynamic hidden fields in the popup could store information about the page the user is on.

Or a better option may be to use Trac which has a Wiki and Bug tracking built in.